# Check if directory is empty in Ruby

Tags: ruby, directory

How can I check to see if a directory is empty or not in Ruby? Is there something like:

```
Dir.exists?("directory")
```

(I know that that function doesn't exist.)

Comment: I'd like to see a method called "Dir.empty?"

Comment: @BenFlynn 5 years later, your wish [has come true](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41344613/2021397)

Comment: @Janosch Either this or proof of the existence of gravitational waves is the best thing to happen in 2016.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

Ruby now has [`Dir.empty?`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Dir.html#method-c-empty-3F), making this trivially easy:

```
Dir.empty?('your_directory') # => (true|false)
```

---

In Rubies prior to 2.4.0 you can just get a list of the entries and see for yourself whether or not it's empty (accounting for "." and ".."). See [the docs](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Dir.html#M000607).

```
(Dir.entries('your_directory') - %w{ . .. }).empty?

# or using glob, which doesn't match hidden files (like . and ..)
Dir['your_directory/*'].empty?
```

*Update: the first method above used to use a regex; now it doesn't (obviously). Comments below mostly apply to the former (regex) version.*

Comment: The first one gave me errors, but the second worked perfectly. Thanks!

Comment: @Mark Szymanski: Ahh yeah I wrapped the block in parentheses. Fixed.

Comment: The first command will also ignore hidden files, like .git though.

Comment: @Pan Thomakos: No it won't. The second will, but the first only rejects filenames consisting of only dots.

Comment: But `...` is a valid filename (as is `....`, ...), I think you'd be better off with an explicit `x == '.' || x == '..'` check than your regex. True, `...` is a pathological case but saying exactly what you mean is a good idea.

Comment: @mu I thought about that, but figured it wasn't too important since it's an edge case and the second method sidesteps the matter all together. Still, though, I'll update just to make sure it doesn't cause someone trouble in the future.

Answer (score 11):

As of Ruby 2.4.0, there is [Dir.empty?](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Dir.html#method-c-empty-3F)

```
Dir.empty?('/') # => false
```

Answer (score 9):

You can use entries to see all files and folders in a directory:

```
Dir.entries('directory')
=> ['.', '..', 'file.rb', '.git']
Dir.entries('directory').size <= 2 # Check if empty with no files or folders.
```

You can also search for files only using glob:

```
Dir.glob('directory/{*,.*}')
=> ['file.rb', '.git']
Dir.glob('directory/{*,.*}').empty? # Check if empty with no files.
```

Comment: But `Dir.glob('directory/*')` will leave out files that begin with `.`, for example `.profile` or `.git`.

Comment: @(mu is too short) - You're correct. I updated my regexp to include hidden files as well.

Comment: Dir.glob('directory/{*,.*}') captures "." and ".." so empty? will always return false.

Answer (score 3):

An empty directory should only have two links (. and ..). On OSX this works:

```
File.stat('directory').nlink == 2
```

...but does not work on Linux or Cygwin. (Thanks @DamianNowak) Adapting Pan's answer:

```
Dir.entries('directory').size == 2
```

should work.

Comment: `nlink` checks for number of subdirectories, which is wrong. `size` should be checked.

Comment: @DamianNowak Not so, try irb File.stat('.').nlink http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/File/Stat.html#method-i-nlink

Comment: Must be OS specific? http://pastie.org/4128791 I am using OSX Lion (11.4.0 Darwin)

Comment: Noticed I am using ruby 1.8.7. "size" returns a number of bytes I believe and therefore does not work on OSX. If you can confirm your OS and Ruby version I'd suggest adding that to the existing answer.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12880/discussion-between-ben-flynn-and-damian-nowak)

Answer (score 1):

Not straightforward but works perfect in *nix kind of systems.

```
Dir.entries(directory_path) == ['.', '..']
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my template for this one.FYI , i am looking for a certain match of files inside the source.

```
mydir = "/home/to/mydir"

Dir.chdir(mydir)

if Dir.entries(mydir).select(|x| x != '.' && x != '..' && x =~ /\regex.txt\z/).size > 0


       do_something 

elsif Dir.entries(mydir).select(|x| x != '.' && x != '..' && x =~ /\regex.txt\z/).size < 0

      do_something_else 

else 

      puts "some warning message"
end
```

let me know if anything :)