# Chef LWRP Only_IF directory not empty

Tags: ruby, chef-infra

Doing a check for wether the directory exist is easy enough with something like:

```
only_if { Dir.exist?(archive_root) }
```

What I'm trying to accomplish is for the only_if to do 2 simultaneous checks.

1. Does the directory exist
2. Only if directory not empty

So if we take a look at a generic execute it should be something like this:

```
execute "RunThisAction" do
  command "ls -al /data/ > /tmp/foo.log"
  action :nothing
  only_if { Dir.exist?("/data") && !Dir.empty?("/data") }
  notifies :run, "execute[ASecondAction]", :immediately
end
```

So the questions are... is that Dir.empty the correct way of doing things?  Second to that if the action gets triggered but the only_if condition is not met will it still notify?

I could do the tests directly in Ruby but that will make the actions run at compile time, instead of execution time.  For instance if I do a test of Dir.exist at compile time it may not exist yet and the directory will almost always be empty if a previous action hasn't been run first.

Thanks.

Comment: In pure ruby `Dir.empty?` not exist, where you found it ?

Comment: I should have added: Dir['/data/*'].empty?  That will check wether the directory is empty without including hidden files like . and ..

Comment: `Dir["**/*"].empty?` I think would do. It collects *directories as files*. Read [this](http://ruby.about.com/od/beginningruby/a/dir2.htm).

Comment: Refer: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5059156/check-if-directory-is-empty-in-ruby