# Can't test if directory already exists from within Fastlane with Ruby

Tags: fastlane, fileutils, ruby-2.5

I can’t test whether a directory exists from within a Fastlane action nor lane. None of the following work for `save_path = "./dir_name"` nor `save_path = "dir_name"` in the current directory (from which `fastlane` is being run):

```
!Dir.empty?(save_path)
!Dir[save_path].empty?
Dir.exist?(save_path)
File.exist?(save_path)
File.directory?(save_path)
```

I even tried to expand the relative path:

`File.exists? File.expand_path(save_path)`

I have referred to the following:

1. [Check if directory is empty in Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5059156/check-if-directory-is-empty-in-ruby)
2. [How to check if a given directory exists in Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1085218/how-to-check-if-a-given-directory-exists-in-ruby)
3. https://blog.bigbinary.com/2017/02/28/dir-emtpy-included-in-ruby-2-4.html
4. https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Dir.html

How does one test to see if a directory exists from within Fastlane? Thank you for reading and for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LOL Well, I discovered my issue. I didn't realize that I had to include the entire path to each of these statements, since I'm using `Dir.foreach` to iterate over part of the filesystem; the updated syntax is:

```
Dir.foreach(save_path) do |dir|
   next if dir == '.' or dir == '..'
   if (File.directory?("#{save_path}#{dir}"))
     begin
       FileUtils.mkdir_p("./#{save_path}#{dir}/images")
     rescue StandardError => e
       UI.message("Failed to make directory ./#{save_path}#{dir}/images: #{e.to_s}")
       return
     end
   end
end
```

This is versus `File.directory?("#{dir}")` in that if statement. I thought that the Ruby `Dir` and `FileUtil` libraries would look relative to the current directory for the remainder of the path.

Answer (score 1):

The correct format to check this:

```
Dir.exist? "#{save_path}"
```

Will return true if it exists or false if not.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Isn't this syntax equivalent to `Dir.exist?(save_path)`, as specified above? I appreciate your insight!

Comment: Yes, you're right, I didn't see that you write it also that way. Glad you found the solution anyway!